# Shopify api: add a link

Tags: api, shopify

I am developing a shopify app.

Is it possible to add a new link to the main menu via the shopify API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log in to your partner account and then create an App you can edit the created App and you will see all the resources at your disposal where you can add a new link.

If you notice also, using the API you can pull and rewrite any asset in a shop to contain a new link. This is discouraged as bad practice. Instead, inject a script tag that does the dirty work.

Comment: There you can add only links to the admin panel, not to the shop frontend. I'd like to add a link to the main menu in the shop frontend.

Comment: ok, so the best solution would be creating a js that finds the menu and appends a link? I already tried but unfortunately every template has a different structure so it's a little complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

Soon as I know the API itself cannot change something inside the theme files... some APPs ask you to apply some code manually in the theme, with proper instructions... maybe this code could add the new menu or dynamically interact to get it.